# RadioButton row select event in p:datatable

Tags: jsf, radio-button, primefaces

RadioButton/Checkbox based row selection is a common use case and DataTable provides a solution for this with column selection mode feature.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                 selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}">`
     <f:facet name="header">
            RadioButton Based Selection
        </f:facet>

        <p:column selectionMode="single" />

        <p:column headerText="Model">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
        </p:column>


        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="View" image="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
                             update="displaySingle" oncomplete="singleCarDialog.show()"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
```

I want to know if I choose the first column's radioButton ,**how I get a event for this.**

- Because I want to let a button disabled when choose the first column or the last column's radioButton .
- And I also want to get the **index** of the column when selected the column ,Now I use the selectedCar to compare the list,and get the index of the column. It looks ugly.Anyone can help me ?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to select. Rows or columns?

Comment: Hi Matt, I want to select the row by .when add the <p:column selectionMode="single" />, every column will have a radioButton, so

Comment: I added an answer how a row select event can be processed.

Comment: I want to know how to get the event when select the radioButton.

Answer (score 1):

***This is a solution for PrimeFaces <= 2.x only.***

There is a good example at [Primeface's showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf). There is an attribute `rowSelectListener` that can be used like this:

```
rowSelectListener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"
```

and in the backing bean:

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Selected", 
                           ((Car) event.getObject()).getModel());  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}
```

Comment: But when I select the radioButton, and click the move up button the method of the onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) will not be invoked .

Comment: If I not user the radioButton ,and only select one entie row , the nRowSelect(SelectEvent event) will be invoked.

Comment: You can see  the case http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: the selectionMode attribute  can be used in the 'p:column'

Comment: @yudong Which primefaces version are you on? I have a documentation here of Primefaces 2.1 and there is no attribute `selectionMode` for the column. But maybe it works for Primefaces 3.0.

Comment: @yudong The listener should be invoked if you click the radioButton (instant ajax selection).

Comment: Can you give me a example about the " The listener should be invoked if you click the radioButton (instant ajax selection) " Thanks.